# How to get Activity Waiting Time from ActivityManager on app launching?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adb, activity-manager

I'm using ADB to show Waiting Time Activity on launching app, the command I used is : `adb shell am start -S -W com.example.app/.MainActicity -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -a android.intent.action.MAIN`
here's the result :

[image: RESULT]

So, my question is how to get programmatically the `waitTime` value ? thanks.

Comment: maybe some filtering on the output given by your `adb shell am start` command?

Comment: I think we can't access to this output !!

Comment: why? you can redirect the output to a file (at least in linux/macos.. but I expect on Windows as well) and based on that filter the info you need

Comment: Yes, it's good idea, but i want to know if there's a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: anyway, the aim is to get this value programmatically if it's possible, else i try your proposition.

Comment: Thank You Lino, for this proposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments sections, having a Linux-based terminal you can retrieve the WaitTime programmatically by parsing the output of the the `am start` command and filtering the value like this:

```
adb shell am start -S -W "com.example.abder.emarque/.Activities.EMarque" -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 
-a android.intent.action.MAIN | grep -i waittime | cut -d' ' -f2

3813
```

whereas `grep -i waittime` filters the line containing the waittime and the `cut` command retrieves the value itself.

Hope this helps.